# Stop UINavigationBar from overlaying content

Tags: ios, ios6, uinavigationbar

I am using a UINavigationController within my application, which was working relatively fine. At some point when displaying a header in my collection view the Navigation Bar appears to have been set to a higher position in the stack which allows content to be rendered underneath it.

Does anyone know how I might render the header below the Navigation Bar, rather than underneath it?

Any help greatly appreciated!

**Edit**

If it helps, I ran the following commands:

```
NSLog(@"Navigation Bar Bounds %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds));
NSLog(@"Navigation Bar Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame));
NSLog(@"Collection View Bounds %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.collectionView.bounds));
NSLog(@"Collection View Frame %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.collectionView.frame));
```

With the output as follows:

```
[4058:907] Navigation Bar Bounds {{0, 0}, {320, 44}}
[4058:907] Navigation Bar Frame {{0, 20}, {320, 44}}
[4058:907] Collection View Bounds {{0, 0}, {320, 504}}
[4058:907] Collection View Frame {{0, -22}, {320, 504}}
```

**End of edit**

I have uploaded the following images to demonstrate the problem:

Inside the Storyboard:

[image: Inside My Storyboard]

When the application loads and what the Navigation Bar is hiding:

[image: When the application opens]
[image: What the Navigation bar is hiding]

Full Storyboard, showing the Navigation Controller and the Root View Controller. The UICollectionView is an IBOutlet in the HomeViewController.h file.

[image: The Full Storyboard]

Comment: Is that a scroll view? So the user can scroll down to reveal the header?

Comment: Not as far as I know, its just a plain view controller with a UICollectionView.

Comment: What's rootViewController?UIViewController or UICollectionViewController?

Comment: I updated the question to show the full storyboard, the Relationship to the Root View Controller is with the `HomeViewController`, which is an instance of `UIVewController` (Eg. `HomeViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, AddPropViewControllerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>`).

Comment: have you tried deleting Home View Controller and creating it again. It seems that some of the property is messed up while creating it.

Comment: I have not tried that yet, although I edited the question to provide the bounds and frame of both the nav and collection view.

Comment: Are you setting frames manually in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear? If so, try setting up the frames in viewDidLayoutSubviews instead (since that happens later, after the rest of the frames are set up).

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of the Sizing tab (the ruler tab) of your Collection View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to change the "tob bar" of your ViewController to "Navigation Bar", and put your controls on it

check this image

[image]